# Difficulty in understanding this Q regarding VOA & Parallel lines

Tags: geometry, triangles

Q: In a triangle $\triangle{ABC}$, $D$ is mid-point of $BC$; $AD$ is produced up to $E$ so that ${DE}={AD}$.

Prove that:

(i) $\triangle{ABD}$ and $\triangle{ECD}$ are congruent.

(ii) $AB=EC$

[image]

In ∆ ABD and ∆ ECD
BD = DC (D is the midpoint of BC)

- ∠ADB = ∠CDE (VOA) *

∠ADB = ∠CDE , it says that VOA online is the answer. I think saying that both are 90 degree is not the correct answer. It should be VOA. Why ?

[image]

Even in this case , the line from A bisects the base of triangle but we can’t say angle is 90. Still , DE = AD condition can be satisfied but just looking at the picture , we can prove that CE ≠ AB.

Therefore , after saying VOA is the property. We must prove how can we use it. The way I see that we can use it is by proving that AD = BD & DE = CD. After that , equal opposite sides have equal opposite angles.

Therefore ,  ∠ABD = ∠DAB & ∠(ECD = CED)

But I need help in proving that BD=AD. I can’t of why is that true.

If you think there is anything else to my Q that I am missing , please share.

AD = DE (Given)
By SAS postulate of congruency of triangles, we have
∆ ABD ≅ ∆ ECD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the congruence of $\triangle BDA$ and $\triangle CDE$, we can use the SAS-postulate:

- $BD = CD$ (because $D$ is the midpoint of the segment $BC$),
- $\angle BDA = \angle CDE$ (since they are vertically opposite angles), and
- $DA = DE$ (given).

It seems that you are trying to prove the wrong thing. You can't prove $BD = AD$, because that is generally false.

Comment: Hmm If you read , I have already written the 2nd point. My Q is how do you prove this condition.

Comment: @S.M.T Hm? You want to prove why $\angle BDA = \angle CDE$? They're vertically opposite angles, so they must be equal. (They do not necessarily have to be right angles, as your second image shows.)

Comment: Ohh. I did a mistake. I thought of VOA in a wrong way.